# Why does catkin add the src directory of the workspace to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and not the devel directory?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the devel space is supposed to mimic the install space, (as described in http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/workspaces), should that not be what is added to the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH? It seems confusing to have the package.xml and .launch files remain in the src directory and the binary targets copied to the devel directory...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75310/why-does-catkin-add-the-src-directory-of-the-workspace-to-ros_package_path-and-not-the-devel-directory?/) by [munnveed](https://answers.ros.org/users/6052/munnveed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2013-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not an expert, but [this](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0124.html#locating-executables-in-catkin-build-directories) catkin-related REP seems to provide the rationale for this design choice.

Basically, the REP says that it would have potentially broken some override capabilities to add *both* locations to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, and it would've been overly complicated to copy all src files to the devel directory on every catkin_make.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [munnveed](https://answers.ros.org/users/6052/munnveed/) on 2013-08-29**:
Thanks. At least it is not the case that I was just missing something obvious.